How to Remove Empty Objects in Jolt Transformation Output?
Issue:
Despite not having contactEnrichment in the input JSON, the output JSON always includes "contactEnrichment": {}. I want to completely omit the contactEnrichment field when it's empty or not present in the input.
Current Behaviour:
{
    "contactEnrichment": {}
}

Question:
How can I modify my Jolt spec to remove the contactEnrichment field from the output JSON when it's empty or not present in the input?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
What I've Tried:
Adjusting the Jolt spec to conditionally include contactEnrichment - couldn't find a way to conditionally remove fields.
Post-processing the JSON to remove empty fields - looking for a more elegant solution within Jolt.

Hi Sanskar, welcome to SO. Can you please clearly add the input, the Jolt transformation you've tried to solve the problem and the desired output as independent three JSON values ?

You can try this:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "contactEnrichment": {
        "*": {
          // If contactEnrichment has any child elements, map them
          "@2,contactEnrichment": "contactEnrichment"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

The contactEnrichment block checks if contactEnrichment contains any child elements.
The @2,contactEnrichment maps the contactEnrichment field only if it has child elements, otherwise it is omitted.
The result in the contactEnrichment field being completely omitted if contactEnrichment is empty or not present in the input JSON.
Here is the result:


Still getting the same issue.

This spec can help you with the required Solution:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "contactEnrichment": {
        "*": "contactEnrichment.&"
      }
    }
  }
]

Explanation :
contactEnrichment object will only populate if there is any field or object inside it.
"contactEnrichment": {
            "*": "contactEnrichment.&"
          }

here we are going inside contactEnrichment object and then shifting each object inside into contactEnrichment again.
i.e.
"*": "contactEnrichment.&" -> now if there is no field inside the object there wont be any shift for contactEnrichment object and it wont populate in final output.
